# How do you find the intersection of two vector lines in 3D space where the point of intersection is the starting point of one line and is unknown?

Tags: linear-algebra

I essentially am trying to solve for the intersection of two vector lines where we've been given two points A and B on the first line and point Q on the second line. Point P also lies on the first line and is the starting point of the second line, therefore being the point of intersection.

I've tried to use the method of converting their vector line equations into parametric ones and setting the x components, y components and z components equal to each other but there are just too many unknowns. It doesn't make sense unless I assume values for t and s which are the scalar component multiplying with the direction vectors of the vector equations. I'll attach the question below.

[image: Question]

Comment: You are overlooking the fact that the staircase needs to be as short as possible. What can you deduce from that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: You will find the answer in MSE if you use the keywords "project point on line"